# Append data frames to and empty variable

Tags: python, pandas, append

I've several data frames which all have the same columns:

```
df_list = [df1,df2,df3,dfn]
```

And I want to append  those to a new data frame if a given condition is satisfied.

```
for df in df_list:
     if some_condition:
           new_df.append(df)
```

But that didn;t work, so I try this:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for column in df1.columns:
    new_df[column] = []
```

And just for testing it:

```
new_df.append(df1)
```

but `new_df` it's still empty.

It only works if I assign it explicity

```
new_df = new_df.append(df1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need append to new list `dfs` and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = []
for df in df_list:
     if some_condition:
           dfs.append(df)

print pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea of way new_df.append(df1) keeps new_df empy?

Comment: I think because [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) doesnt work inplace - `returning a new object`

Comment: I thought it was as in a list.